# NSFileManager & NSFilePosixPermissions

Tags: xcode, permissions, nsdictionary, nsfilemanager, chmod

I want to use the octal permissions (used for chmod) for NSFilePosixPermissions.
Here is what I did now:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *attributes;

[attributes setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 0777] 
             forKey:@"NSFilePosixPermissions"]; // chmod permissions 777
[manager setAttributes:attributes ofItemAtPath:@"/Users/lucky/Desktop/script" error:nil];
```

I get no error, but when I check the result with "ls -o" the permission are't -rwxrwxrwx.

What's wrong?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, `NSFilePosixPermissions` is the name of a constant. Its value may also be the same, but that’s not guaranteed. The value of the `NSFilePosixPermissions` constant could change between framework releases, e. g. from `@"NSFilePosixPermissions"` to `@"posixPermisions"`. This would break your code. The right way is to use the constant as `NSFilePosixPermissions`, not `@"NSFilePosixPermissions"`.

Also, the [NSFilePosixPermissions reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfileposixpermissions?language=objc) says about `NSFilePosixPermisions`:

> The corresponding value is an `NSNumber` object. Use the `shortValue` method to retrieve the integer value for the permissions.

The proper way to set POSIX permissions is:

```
// chmod permissions 777

// Swift
attributes[NSFilePosixPermissions] = 0o777

// Objective-C
[attributes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithShort:0777] 
             forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions];
```

Comment: Thanks! Only set the NSFilePermissions value don't work I did it so: `NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[manager attributesOfItemAtPath:@"file..." error:nil]];`Next step I set the permissions and it worked!

Comment: You can also use literal notation to pass an NSNumber (and NSDictionary): `@{NSFilePosixPermissions: @0777}`

Comment: Note that the leading zero here is critical. That tells the C compiler that your constant is in Octal. Octal 0777 is 511 in decimal, not the same number!

Comment: You say a short. What if the octal I want is 0100640 instead of 0640? That's a perfectly valid octal for C's version of chmod(). However, a C short can only store a number up to 32767 if signed, and 65535 if unsigned. That's not enough to store 0100640.

Comment: No, it’s not me who’s saying that. [Apple is.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW2). Also, this attribute is about the file permissions. `0100000` isn’t a permission bit, however. It’s part of the mode. The permissions are a subset of the mode only.

Comment: For anyone revisiting this with Swift, a leading 0 is not sufficient to indicate a number is octal, you must lead with `0o`. `NSFileManager.defaultManager.setAttributes([NSFilePosixPermissions: NSNumber(short: 0o777)], ofItemAtPath: "/tmp/foo")`

Comment: Added a Swift example. Note that you don’t need to explicitly wrap the value in an `NSNumber`. Swift-Objective-C bridging will do that automatically.

Comment: Has now been updated to posixPermissions in swift 3 https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/fileattributekey/1418260-posixpermissions

Answer (score 4):

**Solution in Swift 3**

```
let fm = FileManager.default

var attributes = [FileAttributeKey : Any]()
attributes[.posixPermissions] = 0o777
do {
    try fm.setAttributes(attributes, ofItemAtPath: path.path)
}catch let error {
    print("Permissions error: ", error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [FilePermissions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/system/filepermissions) type that can make this easier.

You can add an extension:

```
extension FileManager {

  func setUnixPermissions(_ permissions: FilePermissions, atPath: String) throws {
    try FileManager.default.setAttributes(
      [.posixPermissions: permissions.rawValue],
      ofItemAtPath: atPath
    )
  }

}
```

Example usage:

```
  let fm = FileManager.default
  let path = "/path/to/something"

  // FilePermissions.
  try fm.setUnixPermissions([.ownerRead, .groupRead], atPath: path)

  // Octal permissions.
  try fm.setUnixPermissions(FilePermissions(rawValue: 0x777), atPath: path)
```