# NSFileManager - Create a readonly file

Tags: objective-c, readonly, nsfilemanager

I have a file which I created using NSFileManager but could not find a way to make it readonly. I have searched all over the internet and in Apple's [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Resource_Fork_Support) but could not find anything. Here is the code of where the file was created.

```
if ([fm createFileAtPath:fileName contents:inputData attributes:nil] == NO) {
     NSLog(@"Error!");
     return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setAttributes:` of `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` to remove the files read bit. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655185/nsfilemanager-nsfileposixpermissions) posts explains it.

Following sets permissions to -rwxrwxrwx (0777). Replace 0777 with the permissions you desire.

```
NSDictionary *attributes;
[attributes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithShort:0777] forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:attributes ofItemAtPath:@"/path/to/file"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to this so can you provide an example of using the `setAttributes` preferably with this example

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
[attributes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithShort:0777] forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions];

[filemanager setAttributes:atributes ofItemAtPath:yourPath error:nil];
```